# Does it make sense for manned warfare be obsolete in scifi/ modern stories

Tags: science-fiction, warfare

I've recently been doing research about modern warfare and it seems to me that the concept of an army (big men carrying guns) is kinda obsolete/ unnecessary/ high cost for its low effectiveness.

There are planes, ships, and intercontinental missiles that could directly destroy targets. It seems to me that deploying a large scale army is just an easy target for weapons of mass destruction. And that army warfare is just prolonging the battle, you know? Why not just go directly to the enemy base, blow it up, and be done with it?

Even in fiction I see the battlefield as just a backdrop/setting for the "huge scale conflict" and that "this fight is important because theres a lot of people fighting",

While the battle is happening, the main characters just go directly to the enemy base and blow it up, ending the entire "war" just an hour after it started. Like they literally didn't need to mobilize all those people and waste all those resources, they shouldve just blown up the enemy base from the very beginning.

Samples:

Wonder Woman - They win the war when Aries dies

Avengers End Game - There was a scene where the mothership started bombarding everyone, had they done that from the start, captain marvel would have arrived late.

Is there any reason that armies still exist other than flavor?

Comment: In fiction it's just easier to not have to deal with the logistics of many moving pieces on the board, and quickly and decisively resolve conflicts by making up and knocking out a few lynch pins.  Also, you speak as if weapons of mass destruction are used freely. In most settings, they aren't. Therefore, if you don't have a big army, how are you supposed to stop them if they march in their big army? Kind of like nukes. You might not use the nukes, but if you don't have nukes how are you going to stop them from using theirs?

Comment: The purpose of warfare is not to *"blow the enemy base up and be done with it"*. The purpose of warfare is to compel the enemy to conform to your wishes; either give up their land, their cattle and their women, or to give back your land, your cattle and your women. I don't fully see how blowing things up and then going away is helping with that. In addition, blowing up the enemy's infrastructure makes you wonder what exactly you are conquering. (And *Wonder Woman* and othe Hollywood movies are intended as entertainment; they are not intended as courses in the art of war.)

Comment: Basically, various components of the armed forces have different roles. Some serve to defend your objectives; some serve to destroy enemy objectives; some serve to take enemy objectives; some serve to hold enemy objectives; and the majority of the people in the army are there to support those who actually fight to defend, to destroy, to attack or to hold.

Comment: @AlexP Hehe. In other words, Genocides like those in Halo are not representative of warfare. Even then, they need to send in manned forces to achieve an specific objective when it's anything other than "glass the whole damn planet".

Comment: @DKNguyen what Im confused about is that, like what you sa8d, armies stop armies and nukes stop nukes, but my nukes could stop enemy armies so whyd i want to have armies?

Comment: @AlexP same thing, its kinda confusing me cus you can stop enemy objectives with missiles too, it seems like a hassle to mobilize an army when you can just threaten the enemy with missiles? Yknow? You dont need to blow up the enemy you just say, "im gonna blow you up if you dont stop, so stop" or "im gonna blow you up if you dont surrender"

Comment: @Mikester919 You continue to talk as if you can use nukes willy nilly. Your mindset on warfare is WAY too simplistic. Most wars in reality and fiction aren't wars of genocide or neighbours with with no third party observers with which you need to maintain relations with. If only ever handle conflicts by nuking everything, even your friendly neighbours are going to start being very wary of you and do something about it. What do you do then? Nuke them too? Just use normal missiles you say? Well, missiles are consumable & expensive while armies are persistent and can be spread out ever advancing.

Comment: As written, your query is a writing question, which we don't deal with here in Worldbuilding. Since your question directly involves literature --- "sci-fi / modern stories", and also specific third party intellectual properties, and is essentially asking for our opinion on something you're idly curious about, I'm afraid it's not a good fit for this forum. Hence, I'm voting to close. Check out our [tour] and [help] and [what this forum is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worldbuilding-site-about) so you can learn better how this forum works.

Comment: @DKNguyen that doesnt sound very convincing armies are very expensive too. Human personnel have lots of training, practice with live rounds, die, have salaries, other paperwork and are at the end of the day consumables just like missiles. Tho I did find a more satisfactory reason below

Comment: @elemtilas ok im fine with closing, ive gotten an answer, tho i did intend this as a worldbuilding question, mightve come out differently cus of my poor explanation hahaha

Comment: in my opinion you shouldnt to much rely on technology though, because usually most of them is easier to figure out their pattern to counter, while human soldier can be creative on its own sometime. at least use human soldier as backup incase skynet type happen if they get to be advance. outside of you probably need human soldier as subjugate army in enemy territory rather than using cold heart robot.

Comment: Slightly relevant, the short story [Hour of Battle](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29445) by Robert Sheckley. The military bring their automated warfare against literal demons.

Comment: At any rate, what is the goal of your war? If the intent is to obliterate the enemy, then you don't need human armies for that. However, the *vast* majority of wars are control - over some resource, or territory, or just political. In those cases you want the enemy intact after you're finished with them. You need to capture and control what you're after. You can't really do this with drones or nukes. You need actual people to do that for you. How do you propose you actually *win* a war without that? Remember, the goal of the war is to get something - how do you get it with drones and nukes?

Comment: oh yeah also technology can get hacked, even if it has a good hack protection people will find a creative way to hack it, just like many technology today still able to get hacked despite boasting their anti-hack program/tool.

Comment: To re-iterate/clarify what others have said. Nukes/bombs missiles are possibly better than troops and blowing stuff up, and maybe even at "winning" a war. But was is not a game played only in order to "win".War is a tool of statecraft, a means to an end. Work out what the point of the war is ("to save those people from genocide", "this land is rightfully ours", "they should have a democracy too"), then ask yourself again if nuking a country to glass is the best way of getting what you want.

Comment: Alright, thanks

Answer (score 14):

I think you are confusing two ideas. The first is a real world question as to whether or not ground armies are still effective against air power. The second is a narriative one about how armies are portrayed in stories.

Whether or not ground armies are effective is a debate that has now went back over a century. There have been theoretical arguments like Mahan(1890) and Douhet(1921) who have stated that naval and air power can win wars alone. Generally speaking they have been proven wrong. While naval power is extremely valuable in allowing you to limit enemies economically and move your troops around freely, it cannot win offensive wars without ground forces because there is no way to take enemy territory. Likewise, air forces are most effective when used to support ground armies. In the first Gulf War, three times as many Iraqi armored vehicles were destroyed in a hundred hour ground war as were destroyed in several weeks of bombing. And that was in a desert, which is an ideal bombing target. Kosovo was a much worse showing, in which it took over fifty sorties to hit a single target.

Strategic bombing on a larger scale is also of debatable effectiveness overall. While Japan did likely surrender at the end of WW2 due to bombing and a naval blockade, they also had no way to prevent an invasion at that point, which would have led them to ruin. It also required the shock of an atomic bomb instead of just conventional bombing.

Nuclear weapons are said to be the thing that makes conventional armies obsolete, but they are also not useful in the direct sense either, because no one can afford to use them. They do make it impossible to threaten the survival of an enemy nation with ground armies, but this doesn't make ground armies inherently useless either. If the US Army hadn't had soldiers in Europe and had simply relied on the nuclear arsenal to protect Europe, the question of whether the US is willing to give up Manhattan or Washington DC to protect Berlin becomes an important political issue. Having American soldiers in Europe die makes it much easier to sell using them to the American public, which then serves as an effective deterrent to prevent the Soviets from making a move in the first place.

Ground armies that are too small(or too reliant upon air forces) and have the ability to destroy enemies but then can't control the territory is why the Iraq war was such a problem. The US military was easily able to destroy the Iraqi army in three weeks. It took over a decade to occupy the country with insufficient numbers, and it's debatable that they ever actually succeeded in the first place.

The narrative problem that stories have a hard time with any sort of collective action is a separate issue. Stories of large wars almost always wind up telling the story of small groups within the wider conflict as opposed to the large battles that really decide it. The overuse of commandos and spies as opposed to the large divisional units that actually win wars is a symptom of the fact that it is hard to dramatize big events as anything other than backdrop. Also, for the Wonder Woman example, the actual First World Wars was absolutely won by the Western Allies having superior numbers and logistics at the end of the War after the US joined. Using fiction to understand history is an extremely foolish way to learn about it.

Comment: Omg I love this answer!! This is really hepful! This question is made primarily for a fictional setting, I'm trying to write a world in wartime, but I just can't make sense of having an army in my world when things bigger than nukes also exist (its sci fi fantasy). I cant think of why my world needed an army and I didnt want to just hand wave the explanation in my mind so i tried thinking of how its applicable in the real world and in other stories but I also didnt find an answer so i went here. Thanks Adam Reynolds. Helps a lot! Could I also ask where I can find other relevant information?

Comment: I guess im going to be reading about the effectiveness of missiles in eliminating ground threats next

Answer (score 5):

welcome to Worldbuilding.se. Yours is an interesting question that might get closed because it's not presented as a worldbuilding question. You're not asking about a fictional world of your own design nor, necessarily, the rules and application of those rules that govern it. Please take a moment to read through our [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site works.

However, I do believe that the gist of your question would be valuable to the worldbuilding efforts of others because you're asking about the application of technology and its consequences, which would be on-topic had you asked about your own world.

**So, why use human combatants in the future?**

1. Humans are cheap. Oh, it may be expensive to train and equip them, but they're pretty easy to replace. And no matter how expensive it was to train them, that [trillion-dollar-over-its-production-lifespan](http://interactive.aviationtoday.com/avionicsmagazine/august-september-2018/f-35-is-the-trillion-dollar-fighter-finally-worth-it/) F-35 (with the handy-dandy ACME remote-control upgrade package!) is a LOT more expensive.  To be fair, I'm comparing that F-35 to a WWII-style grunt, your average infantryman sent onto the field to fill the air with lead. That guy today [costs about $45,000](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/3072945/t/army-one-carries-high-price/#.XzngGzV7l9M) to put into the field. Why the disclaimer? Because the military is becoming less and less cheap infantry and more and more expensive education. That might be a pretty good argument in favor of future wars being all drones and missiles, but let's continue. My point is that over the 55-year projected lifespan of the F-35 you could field a 33-million-man army.  And that was *just one type of plane.*

*Further disclaimer: it may only cost a bottle of Tequila to create a new human, but getting that human to 18 years of age with enough physical fitness, mental acuity, and low jail-time to be acceptable to the military has its own costs. But that cost isn't usually borne by the government as a consequence of war. So we'll ignore it.*

2. Unless you invoke [Clarkean magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws), we're unlikely to have artificial intelligence running those drones. That means remote control. It's easy to stop remote control. Detonate a nuke (or a [pinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)), or any other way of creating an [EMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse)). In fact, Mother Nature can wreak merry havoc with remote control. What I'm saying is that drones are not universally deployable (at least not yet), although methinks they're close.
3. Armies are very good at keeping the battlefield away from civilians. This assertion might not seem true when you look at the history of warfare, but the reality is, unless somebody's mean-natured enough to hunker-down in a town, towns tend to get left alone unless they have some sort of *strategic importance* (like having the misfortune of hosting the only bridge over the big, nasty river). Generally speaking, battles are something the general population read about in newspapers but don't often participate in directly. If you remove the armies, what's left are military bases and things civilians depend on, like cities, dams, power stations, etc. It may be undesirable to tempt your enemy to whack away at your civilian population — but that does require everybody to be fighting within the same set of "rules." That was one of the problems that took the West by surprise when they fought in Korea and Vietnam — the opposing forces simply didn't think like westerners, and therefore didn't fight like westerners, and until we realized that fighting is ugly all the way around, we thought it was somehow *unfair.*  Nevertheless, I consider this a valid reason for wanting troops.
4. Deploying people is often cheaper than deploying raw technology. You can land an awful lot of soldiers for the cost of landing, say, remote controlled tanks (which has been done in SciFi, see the [Bolo universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolo_universe)). In fact, an enemy might consider a standing army (well, a regiment maybe) a lower threat than a bunch of hangars filled with remote-controlled doom. That was the basic problem with the [Cuban Missile Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuban_Missile_Crisis). The U.S. wasn't worried about the presence of military personnel in Cuba, but when the Russians started placing nukes on the island we became very worried very fast. High tech is a lot more threatening than soldiers.

*In fact, if you think about it, China has more than [2 million soldiers](https://www.statista.com/statistics/264443/the-worlds-largest-armies-based-on-active-force-level/), which many (if not most) people never stop to think about (at least over here in the U.S.). On the other hand, we care a lot about Russia's remaining nuclear arsenal.*

**Having said that, what would be the opposite argument?**

Frankly, the biggest argument against continued use of ground combat troops in the future is one simple truth — tech gets cheaper over time. Yes, the F-35 would seem to deny that, but the reality is that the F-35 represents the best we can make right now (at least the best we know about, you never know what new tech the scientists at Area 51 will strip off those alien space ships). If we started turning out a bazillion cruise missiles the entire nature of war would change.

And that's what you as a new worldbuilder need to think about. Cruise missiles are cheap, but their use would also change the nature of war. After all, there isn't a battlefield to hit anymore, and not as many military bases, either. That means you're hitting industrial complexes, resource centers... and cities.

All those men are starting to look better already.

Comment: Thanks! This gives good insight on the topic!